# Sobrescritura en la variable $_SESSION[]

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, base-de-datos

He estado trabajando en una página en donde la principal función es mostrar las notas de cada competencia de un estudiante en especifico; estos tendrán un usuario único. La cosa es lo siguiente...

Ya tengo la funcionalidad lista de mi página web y para eso probe en iniciar sesion y efectivamente funcionó. Luego, trate de iniciar dos sesiones al mismo tiempo (inicie sesion en una pestaña y luego inicie la segunda sesion en otra pestaña diferente). Pero lo que pasó es que se sobrescribía la información, es decir,la información del primer usuario que se logueo, se observaba que era las notas del segundo usuario (este último usuario si se les mostraba las notas respectivas de él). Y ya rebice mi codigo php y las solicitudes AJAX y aún así nada. La verdad no sé que pueda estar provocando esa mala lectura de datos.

ARCHIVO PHP DONDE SE VALIDA EL INICIO DE SESION DEL USUARIO

```
<?php
 session_start();
 include('conexion.php');

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
   

    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM estudiante WHERE estudiante.numero_documento_estudiante = 
    '$usuario' AND estudiante.contraseña = '$pass'; ";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conec,$sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado))
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = array(
            'numero_documento' => $row['numero_documento_estudiante'],
            'contraseña' => $row['contraseña'],
            'primer_nombre' => $row['primer_nombre'],
            'segundo_nombre' => $row['segundo_nombre'],
            'primer_apellido' => $row['primer_apellido'],
            'segundo_apellido' => $row['segundo_apellido'],
        );
       echo 1;
    }else{
        echo "Error: Ha digitado mal su usuario o contraseña";
    }

}

?>
```

HTML DONDE SE MUESTRA LA INFORMACION DEL USUARIO (NOTAS DEL ESTUDIANTE) DEPENDIENDO DE LA MATERIA QUE SELECCIONE Y PERIODO ACADEMICO (O CONOCIDO TAMBIÉN COMO SEMESTRE):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Interfaz del estudiante</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <?php
    session_start();
include('conexion.php');
$nombre = $_SESSION['usuario']['primer_nombre']." ".$_SESSION['usuario']['segundo_nombre']." ".$_SESSION['usuario']['primer_apellido']." ".$_SESSION['usuario']['segundo_apellido'];
echo  "<h2 id='nombre'>$nombre</h2>";
$numero_documento_estudiante = $_SESSION['usuario']['numero_documento'];
$sql = "SELECT curso.curso FROM curso INNER JOIN curso_estudiante ON curso.id_curso = curso_estudiante.fk_id_curso INNER JOIN estudiante ON estudiante.numero_documento_estudiante = curso_estudiante.fk_numero_documento_estudiante WHERE estudiante.numero_documento_estudiante = '$numero_documento_estudiante';";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conec,$sql);
$array_asociativo_grupo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
$grupo = $array_asociativo_grupo['curso'];
echo "<h4>$grupo</h4>";
$sql2 = "SELECT DISTINCT materia.materia,materia.id_materia FROM materia INNER JOIN competencia ON competencia.fk_id_materia = materia.id_materia INNER JOIN curso_competencia ON curso_competencia.fk_id_competencia = competencia.id_competencia INNER JOIN curso ON curso.id_curso = curso_competencia.fk_id_curso WHERE curso.curso = '$grupo';";
$resultado2 = mysqli_query($conec,$sql2);
echo "<div class='btn_materias'>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado2)){
    $materia = $row['materia'];
    $id = $row['id_materia'];
    echo "<button type='submit' class='materia' materiaId=$id>$materia</button>";

};
echo "</div>";
?>

    <div>
        <title></title>
        <div>
            <?php 
            $sql3 = "SELECT periodo_academico.periodo,periodo_academico.id_periodo_academico FROM periodo_academico;"; 
            $resultado3 = mysqli_query($conec,$sql3);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado3)){
                $periodo_academico = $row['periodo'];
                $id_periodo_academico = $row['id_periodo_academico'];
                echo "<button type='submit' class='periodo' periodoId=$id_periodo_academico disabled>$periodo_academico periodo</button>";
            }
            
            ?>

        </div>
        <table class="competencias">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>competencias</td>
                    <td>notas</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <ul id="competencias">
                            
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                    <td id="notas">

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div id="sin_notas">
            
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-eKhayi8LEQwp4NKxN+CfCh+3qOVUtJn3QNZ0TciWLP4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="estudiante.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

JS EN DONDE SE AGREGA LAS FUNCIONALIDADES DE LA PAGINA Y JUNTO A LA PETICIÓN AJAX QUE SE REALIZA:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    let btn_periodos = document.getElementsByClassName('periodo');
    let btn_materias = document.getElementsByClassName('materia');
    

    // Función para borrar los datos
    function borrarDatos() {
        document.getElementById('competencias').innerHTML = '';
        document.getElementById('notas').innerHTML = '';
         // Asegurarse de borrar el mensaje
        for (let i = 0; i < btn_periodos.length; i++) {
            btn_periodos[i].classList.remove('active');
        }

    }

    // Agregar controladores de eventos para los botones de materia
    for (let index = 0; index < btn_materias.length; index++) {
        btn_materias[index].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            // Remover la clase 'active' de todos los botones de materia
            for (let i = 0; i < btn_materias.length; i++) {
                btn_materias[i].classList.remove('active');
            }
            // Agregar la clase 'active' al botón de materia seleccionado
            e.target.classList.add('active');
            let id_materia = e.target.getAttribute('materiaId');
            console.log(id_materia);
            // Habilitar los botones de período
            for (let i = 0; i < btn_periodos.length; i++) {
                btn_periodos[i].disabled = false;
            }
            // Borrar los datos cuando se cambie de materia
            borrarDatos();
        });
    }

    // Agregar un solo controlador de eventos para los botones de período
    for (let index = 0; index < btn_periodos.length; index++) {
        btn_periodos[index].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            let id_periodo = e.target.getAttribute('periodoId');
            let id_materia = document.querySelector('.materia.active').getAttribute('materiaId');
            for (let i = 0; i < btn_periodos.length; i++) {
                btn_periodos[i].classList.remove('active');
            }
            e.target.classList.add('active');
            $.ajax({
                url: 'estudiante_datos.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { id_materia, id_periodo },
                success: (response) => {

                    if (response != 0) {
                        let competencias_notas = JSON.parse(response);
                        let competencias = '';
                        let notas = '';
                        competencias_notas.forEach(element => {
                            competencias += `
                                <li>
                                    ${element.competencia}
                                </li>
                            `;
                            notas += `
                                <li>
                                    ${element.calificacion}
                                </li>`;
                        });
                        document.getElementById('competencias').innerHTML = competencias;
                        document.getElementById('notas').innerHTML = notas;
                        document.getElementById('sin_notas').innerHTML = '';
                        console.log(response)
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById('sin_notas').innerHTML = 'No hay notas registradas en este periodo';
                        borrarDatos()
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

ARCHIVO PHP DONDE REALIZA LA RESPUESTA A LA PETICIÓN AJAX PARA MOSTRAR LA INFORMACION DE LAS NOTAS DE CADA USUARIO:

```
<?php

session_start();

include('conexion.php');

$numero_documento_estudiante = $_SESSION['usuario']['numero_documento'];
$id_materia = intval($_POST['id_materia']);
$id_periodo = intval($_POST['id_periodo']);
$sql = "SELECT curso.curso FROM curso_estudiante INNER JOIN curso ON curso.id_curso = curso_estudiante.fk_id_curso WHERE curso_estudiante.fk_numero_documento_estudiante = '$numero_documento_estudiante';";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conec,$sql);
$fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
$grupo = $fila['curso'];
$sql2 = "SELECT competencia.competencia,calificacion_competencia.calificacion FROM materia INNER JOIN competencia ON competencia.fk_id_materia = materia.id_materia INNER JOIN curso_competencia ON curso_competencia.fk_id_competencia = competencia.id_competencia INNER JOIN curso ON curso.id_curso = curso_competencia.fk_id_curso INNER JOIN calificacion_competencia ON calificacion_competencia.fk_id_competencia = competencia.id_competencia INNER JOIN estudiante ON estudiante.numero_documento_estudiante = calificacion_competencia.fk_numero_documento_estudiante INNER JOIN periodo_academico ON competencia.fk_id_periodo_academico = periodo_academico.id_periodo_academico WHERE estudiante.numero_documento_estudiante = '$numero_documento_estudiante' AND curso.curso = '$grupo' AND materia.id_materia = $id_materia AND periodo_academico.id_periodo_academico = $id_periodo";
$resultado2 = mysqli_query($conec,$sql2);
$jsonstring = array();
if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado2)){
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado2)){
    $jsonstring[] = array(
        'competencia' => $row['competencia'],
        'calificacion' => $row['calificacion']
    );
}


$json = json_encode($jsonstring);
echo $json;
}else{
    echo 0;
}
/* foreach ($_SESSION['usuario']as $key => $value) {
    echo $value;
} */
?>
```

Si sirve de algo, aquí hay una imagen de mas o menos como se ve y funciona la página junto con la problematica que se está presentando:

primer usuario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

segundo usuario

[image]

La información en la base de datos que tengo no coincide con la que se muestra en la página (el estudiante Carlos no posee las notas que se muestra en pantalla):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces ese es mi problema, como pueden ver, parece que se esta sobrescribiendo, pero la verdad no estoy seguro que lo este ocasionando. Y por sí solo (es decir, sin iniciar dos sesiones al mismo tiempo) muestra bien la informacion del usuario, el problema solamente radica cuando son varias sesiones abiertas simultaneamente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te diré unas cuantas cosas.

1- Las sesiones son por navegador, no por pestaña. Si abres *una nueva pestaña*, en primer lugar no deberías poder acceder al login ya que la sesión tendría que enviarte al index, primer error. Te digo esto porque tu explícitamente dices PESTAÑA y no navegador. Puedes usar el modo incógnito del mismo navegador y ahí si es válido.

2- Para el archivo HTML, te digo lo siguiente.

```
<?php
   // Si usas sesiones, session_start debe ser tu primer línea de código. SIEMPRE !!!
    session_start();
include('conexion.php');
$nombre = $_SESSION['usuario']['primer_nombre']." ".$_SESSION['usuario']['segundo_nombre']." ".$_SESSION['usuario']['primer_apellido']." ".$_SESSION['usuario']['segundo_apellido'];
echo  "<h2 id='nombre'>$nombre</h2>";
$numero_documento_estudiante = $_SESSION['usuario']['numero_documento'];
$sql = "SELECT curso.curso FROM curso INNER JOIN curso_estudiante ON curso.id_curso = curso_estudiante.fk_id_curso INNER JOIN estudiante ON estudiante.numero_documento_estudiante = curso_estudiante.fk_numero_documento_estudiante WHERE estudiante.numero_documento_estudiante = '$numero_documento_estudiante';";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conec,$sql);
$array_asociativo_grupo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
$grupo = $array_asociativo_grupo['curso'];
echo "<h4>$grupo</h4>";
$sql2 = "SELECT DISTINCT materia.materia,materia.id_materia FROM materia INNER JOIN competencia ON competencia.fk_id_materia = materia.id_materia INNER JOIN curso_competencia ON curso_competencia.fk_id_competencia = competencia.id_competencia INNER JOIN curso ON curso.id_curso = curso_competencia.fk_id_curso WHERE curso.curso = '$grupo';";
$resultado2 = mysqli_query($conec,$sql2);
echo "<div class='btn_materias'>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado2)){
    $materia = $row['materia'];
    $id = $row['id_materia'];
    echo "<button type='submit' class='materia' materiaId=$id>$materia</button>";

};
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Interfaz del estudiante</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
<?php
// No hagas esto, PHP solo debe manejar datos, todo el HTML hazlo con HTML
echo "</div>";
?>

    <div>
        <title></title>
        <div>
            <?php 
            $sql3 = "SELECT periodo_academico.periodo,periodo_academico.id_periodo_academico FROM periodo_academico;"; 
            $resultado3 = mysqli_query($conec,$sql3);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado3)){
                $periodo_academico = $row['periodo'];
                $id_periodo_academico = $row['id_periodo_academico'];
                echo "<button type='submit' class='periodo' periodoId=$id_periodo_academico disabled>$periodo_academico periodo</button>";
            }
            
            ?>

        </div>
        <table class="competencias">
```

3- Cuando mezclas PHP + HTML debe ser así. Aprende el uso de las comillas dobles y simples también.

```
<?php
$link = 'https://misitio.com';
?>

<html>
<body>
<a href="<?php echo $link; ?>">Visita mi Web</a>
</body>
<html>
```

Solo imprimes o haces `echo` de las variables y datos, todo el HTML debe ser puro, así como el PHP puro. No mezcles haciendo un `echo '<div>';`

Con respecto al JS no te puedo decir mucho porque si logras resolver el tema sesiones ahí se solventa todo.

Comment: Muchas gracias!. Lo que me comentastes de usar el modo incógnito funcionó, pero como funciona realmente?. Acaso no se debe de iniciar dos sesiones diferentes al mismo tiempo como lo estaba haciendo, y en su lugar debería implementar esa acción de devolverme al index como lo comentastes sí es el caso de que el usuario ya se logueo anteriormente?.

Y acerca de mezclar php y html; gracias, haré lo que me dices, la verdad no tenía idea de eso.

Comment: Lo que te dije, las sesiones son por navegador, tu puedes tener 6 sesiones usando 3 diferentes navegadores, Chrome, FireFox y Brave, por ejemplo. Cada uno de ellos te permitirá entrar de manera normal y en su modo incógnito. Con respecto a lo del login, si tu ya tienes una sesión activa y vas a `midominio.es/login`. El "archivo login" primeramente debe revisar tu sesión, si ya esta iniciada te debe mandar a `index` o al `dashboard` o lo que sea que tu tengas como home.

Answer (score 1):

En los sistemas web si ya tienes iniciada sesión y vuelves a abrir tu `login.php` en otra pestaña (dentro del mismo navegador), no te debería mostrar  tu login de nuevo, sino te debería redirigir a tu `index.php` ya que en teoría no deberías volver a iniciar sesión si no la has cerrado. En caso de que sí te muestre tu `login.php` teniendo ya una sesión activa, y vuelves a iniciar sesión, tu variables iniciales de sesión se sobreescribirán, esto es porque no puedes tener dos sesiones abiertas al mismo tiempo en tu navegador, es una u otra (y esto es un error del desarrollador).

Pero claro, esto de que no te muestre el `login.php` si ya tienes iniciada sesión es una validación que tú debes hacer manualmente si no usas un framework y esto se hace para todos los sistemas web.

Puedes utilizar este fragmento al inicio de tu `login.php` para realizar la validación, básicamente si tienes declaradas tus variables de sesión, si es un arreglo y si algún índice existe dentro de este, significa que ya has iniciado sesión y te va a redirigir a tu index, en caso contrario, sí te va a mostrar tu login.

```
<?php
@session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION) && is_array($_SESSION) && array_key_exists('registrado', $_SESSION)) {
    header('location:index.php');
    exit();
}
?>
```

Por cierto, como dato adicional, sólo puedes tener una sesión abierta del sistema POR NAVEGADOR (el modo incógnito cuenta como "otro navegador"). Es así como puedes tener, por ejemplo, tu correo electrónico con sesión iniciada en tu Chrome, otro en el incógnito de Chrome, otro en Firefox, otro en el incógnito de Firefox y así, pero nunca dos sobre el mismo, ya que se te van a sobrescribir las variables de sesión como te pasó, aunque en principio es raro que ocurra porque ya de por sí están validados para que no puedas ver el login con sesión iniciada.

Comment: Muchas gracias por las aclaraciones y por el fragmento de codigto!. He entendido y me funciona el codigo que me haz compartido, te lo agradezco mucho.

Comment: Pero me gustaría hacer otra pregunta. Al momento de cerrar sesion y redireccionar al usuario al login, me gustaría deshabilitar el botón de retroceder del navegador ya que se encuentra habilitado cuando se redirecciona al usuario al login una vez que este cierre su sesion; esto provoca que al  precionar en el botón del navegador de devolverse mostrará el home, pero sin ninguna información guardada del usuario en el array $_SESSION[] provocando así mensajes de errores dispersos en el home.  Entonces, Como deshabilito ese botón  del navegador o evito esos errores?

Comment: @Mattteuz El botón de "atrás" del navegador no se puede desactivar, ya que hace una función nativa no modificable, en lo que sí tienes poder es sobre tu sistema. Si cierras sesión, te redirige al login y hasta ahí está bien, pero si le das "atrás" no te debería volver a mostrar tu index.php, tu home ni nigún archivo dentro de tu sistema, ya que la sesión está cerrada. Puedes intentar usar `<?php
@session_start();
if($_SESSION['registrado']!="si"  ){    header("Location: login.php");       die(); }
?>` al principio de tus archivos para validar si hay algo en una variable de sesión.